# Set a variable date to six months prior to today

Tags: c#, variables, datetime

I am trying to set a variable that calculates the date six months prior to today's date.

`string exampleDate = (DateTime.TodaysDate) - (00/06/00)`

Or something like that... I know the above definitely does not work.

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
var sixMonthsPriorToNow = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
```

Comment: Yep.. bedtime for me. I forgot to negate the 6.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
// if you want to convert to string:
string myDate = date.ToString();
```

Comment: My $0.02 worth is that I would explicitly state DateTime time rather than var .... Everyone seems to use it now

Comment: Well, it certainly sounds resonable, though I prefer to use `var` on SO because code snippets are shorter.

Comment: Yeah, agree... But as the OP said 'string exampleDate' then it could be misunderstood that the result was Not actually a string type, but DateTime type